# AddObject() method very slow

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I have a strange problem, when I try to use ObjectSet(TEntity).AddObject() to add a new Entity it is very slow compared to the normal behavior, it takes like 500ms and it happens just in one occasion and I am sure that the instruction which take some time is the AddObject and not the SaveChanges.

The code is very simple

```
    ObjectEntity obj = businessObj.ExtractEntityObj();
    context.ObjectTable.AddObject(ObjectEntity);
```

I do some work to the ObjectContext before to call this part of code but it's not much more than what I do in all the other operations, **It seems that it depends on how many items with the same foreign key are stored in database**, I know it could sound weird but it's the only variable that makes change the performance of this same instruction. I have also noticed that if I try that on a new DataContext the performance goes back to normal (few milliseconds) but for architectural problem I can't have new DataContext each time I have to accomplish something.

Could someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: You must provide more details. This is like: *I have one special case where this happens but I will not tell you anything about that case. Why is that happening?*

Comment: As said, hard to tell without knowing more. But even then I sense a performance profiling session coming, and that's something you'll have to do yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue, maybe could be helpfull to someone, it was due to a simple query I was doing before that instruction, this one:

```
int id = context.ObjectTable.Where(t=>t.Something = somethingElse).FirstOrDefault().ID
```

I still don't know why but this instruction attaches all "ObjectTable" data to the context making it very slow, "ObjectTable" is also the same table in which I was adding the new entity.
**Setting the ObjectQuery MergeOption to NoTracking I have resolved the problem**

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query

```
int id = context.ObjectTable.Where(t=>t.Something = somethingElse).FirstOrDefault().ID
```

to

```
int id = context.ObjectTable.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Something = somethingElse).ID
```

It should't have any significant performance improvement but why use `Where()` and then `FirsOrDefault()`.